# No handlers could be found for logger "cuckoo"

Tags: python, django, sandbox, cuckoo

Error
I am running the Cocosandbox project.
But I get this error when running Coco command

Oops! Cuckoo failed in an unhandled exception!
Sometimes bugs are already fixed in the development release, it is therefore recommended to retry with the latest development release available https://github.com/cuckoosandbox/cuckoo
If the error persists please open a new issue at https://github.com/cuckoosandbox/cuckoo/issues

```
=== Exception details ===
Cuckoo version: 2.0.7
OS version: posix
OS release: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
Python version: 2.7.18
Python implementation: CPython
Machine arch: x86_64
Modules: alembic:1.0.10 androguard:3.0.1 argparse:1.2.1 attrs:21.4.0 beautifulsoup4:4.5.3 capstone:3.0.5rc2 cffi:1.15.1 chardet:2.3.0 click:6.6 colorama:0.3.7 configparser:4.0.2 contextlib2:0.6.0.post1 cryptography:3.3.2 cuckoo:2.0.7 django-extensions:1.6.7 django:1.8.4 dpkt:1.8.7 ecdsa:0.18.0 egghatch:0.2.3 elasticsearch:5.3.0 enum34:1.1.10 flask-sqlalchemy:2.4.0 flask:0.12.2 functools32:3.2.3.post2 future:0.18.3 gevent:1.2.2 greenlet:2.0.2 httpreplay:0.2.6 idna:2.10 importlib-metadata:2.1.3 ipaddress:1.0.23 itsdangerous:1.1.0 jinja2:2.9.6 jsbeautifier:1.6.2 jsonschema:3.2.0 mako:1.1.6 markupsafe:1.1.1 olefile:0.43 oletools:0.51 pathlib2:2.3.7.post1 peepdf:0.4.2 pefile2:1.2.11 pillow:3.2.0 pip:20.3.4 pycparser:2.21 pycrypto:2.6.1 pyelftools:0.24 pyguacamole:0.6 pymisp:2.4.106 pymongo:3.0.3 pyopenssl:21.0.0 pyrsistent:0.16.1 python-dateutil:2.4.2 python-editor:1.0.4 python-magic:0.4.12 python:2.7.18 pythonaes:1.0 requests:2.13.0 roach:0.1.2 scandir:1.10.0 scapy:2.3.2 setuptools:44.1.1 sflock:0.3.10 six:1.16.0 sqlalchemy:1.3.3 tlslite-ng:0.6.0 typing:3.10.0.0 unicorn:1.0.1 urllib3:1.26.18 wakeonlan:0.2.2 werkzeug:1.0.1 wheel:0.37.1 wsgiref:0.1.2 yara-python:3.6.3 zipp:1.2.0

No handlers could be found for logger "cuckoo"
```